# Most proper way to launch a bunch of apps

Tags: gnome, startup-applications

I have a bunch of apps that I use constantly: Chromium, Thunderbird, Terminator, Double Commander, Sublime, etc...

What's the **proper Ubuntu way** to launch them all at once? Not having to launch each one of them...

Should I add an entry in Startup applications for every one? Should I continue using a `start_apps.sh` script like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup doublecmd & nohup thunderbird & nohup skype & nohup subl & nohup clementine & nohup terminator & nohup chromium-browser
```

and using `alt+f2` -> run `./scripts/start_apps`?

gnome-shell @ 12.04

Comment: Define "proper Ubuntu way".

Comment: As I am quite a novice, I'd say it as "experienced user's way".

Comment: You can add your script to startup applications, saving you the trouble of starting it manually. You can also add a short sleep first or in between, this prevents that the rest of ubuntu slows down because all applications start at the same time. also you don't need the nohup in the script.

Comment: I think it is the matter of opinion rather then experience.

Comment: Whatever you prefer and works best for is what you should do. Experience of others is irrelevant to how you are best able to get what you need/want to do done. You could request ideas on how this process could be streamlined, however.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Gerhard, I like your solution. Post it as an answer and I'll acccept it.